# How would a NOT gate be implemented by Josephson Junctions

Tags: superconductors

I'm interested in learning how Josephson Junctions can be utilized to create invertible logic gates. To me it's not clear how the Junctions provide any logical capability (they simply allow for a current flow across an insulating channel but lack any switch type mechanism).

Link to Josephson Effect: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Josephson_effect

Does anyone have a circuit diagram of a NOT gate implemented purely using josephson junctions and wires? I'm hoping to find something similar to the famous CMOS not-gate diagram below: (source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverter_(logic_gate))

[image]

Comment: Isn't something that allows current to flow conditionally the same as a MOSFET or other transistor in principle?

Comment: I don't believe it allows current to flow conditionally. My understanding is a superconducting current can unconditionally flow through a josephson junction. So this is where I get confused as to how create a transistor or some other logical element out of it

Comment: Please read a little about J-junctions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a controllable switch type element to create logic functions of any kind. J-junctions do not seem to provide that.